# Example of a sequence of r.v.'s with constant stopping time that is not a Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Could anybody give me a simple example of a sequence of random variables $(X_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ that has constant expectation, but is not a martingale?

Comment: Question amended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(S_n)$ is a simple symmetric random walk on the integers, then $X_n:=S_n^3$ is a mean zero process that is not a martingale.

Comment: +1. This might well be one of the simplest examples--hence one of the best.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the kind words (again!)